# How to fix : Frame rate differs from source after encoding certain mp4 videos to wmv

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, frame-rate, wmv

I'm having trouble with a usually working ffmpeg script for encoding mp4 and more to wmv. The goal is to keep it like the original, except for the resolution (smaller) and the format (wmv).

When it usually works for a lot of videos, on some of them it doesn't... and i would like to understand and avoid that.

I tried several things, forcing the framerate for the output, using -vsync 2 option, -vsync 0 also.. noone of that fixed the issue.

An other thing, worth adding, is that the fps value from media info is good (24 fps) on the output like the input, but through the M$ windows explorer, it says 30 frames per sec, and when you play the video you see that the text that was matching the input doesn't match the output any more (because of the fps mismatching).

Below the script i use :

```
ffmpeg -threads auto -i input.mp4 -s 480*320 -b:v 1000k -vcodec msmpeg4 -acodec wmav2 -f asf output.wmv
```

Here is the ffmpeg log :

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1-1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './test_2k-24__hq_960x540.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2019-05-27T14:37:50.000000Z
  Duration: 01:28:52.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1232 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 960x540, 1091 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-27T14:37:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 137 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-27T14:37:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> wmav2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, asf, to '/nas/copiedetravail/test_2k-24__hq_960x540.mp4.wmv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p(progressive), 480x320, q=2-31, 1000 kb/s, 24 fps, 1k tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-27T14:37:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 msmpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-27T14:37:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 wmav2
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 31 times
frame=  228 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=     291kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate= 252.4kbits/s speed=18.9x    
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 1 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 1 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 1 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 5 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=  449 fps=449 q=2.0 size=     663kB time=00:00:18.98 bitrate= 286.2kbits/s speed=  19x    
frame=  629 fps=418 q=1.6 size=    1307kB time=00:00:26.16 bitrate= 409.2kbits/s speed=17.4x    
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 30 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 7 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 2 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 34 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=  821 fps=410 q=2.0 size=    1960kB time=00:00:34.26 bitrate= 468.7kbits/s speed=17.1x    
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 71 times
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 2 dct coefficients to -127..127
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 82 times
frame= 1026 fps=409 q=2.0 size=    2695kB time=00:00:42.96 bitrate= 513.8kbits/s speed=17.1x    
[msmpeg4 @ 0x5648e407cb60] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 102 times
frame= 1202 fps=400 q=1.6 size=    3754kB time=00:00:50.13 bitrate= 613.4kbits/s speed=16.7x  
......
frame=127987 fps=301 q=2.0 Lsize=  753842kB time=01:28:52.77 bitrate=1158.0kbits/s speed=12.6x    
video:650704kB audio:83244kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.710554%
```

EDIT :
My workaround was to encode to MPEG, doing this, i'm able to read my file and the frame rate is same as source. If someone knows why it couldn't keep the original framerate in wmv, i'm still interested to know.

Comment: The output shows expected timing. *text that was matching the input* --> which text is this?

Comment: @Gyan subtitles done on the original mp4 file.. i found out that when encoding the file to .mpeg format, the framerate is same as orig, I tried first with :     ffmpeg -i "$1" -b 1500k -acodec wmav2 "$1.wmv"     for wmv and then replaced .wmv with .mpeg, It now keeps the framerate like input file... but why does it not with .wmv ...